# Pyspark convert an array of json column to a pandas list of dict column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

I have pyspark dataframe that I want to convert into a pandas dataframe, however I have an array of json column that gets converted into a string in pandas

```py
my_df = (
spark
.createDataFrame(
  pd.DataFrame([['Scott', 50], ['Jeff', 45], ['Thomas', 54], ['Ann',34]], columns=['id', 'score']))
)

my_df
.groupBy('id')
.agg(
  F.to_json(
    F.sort_array(
      F.collect_list(F.col('score')), asc=False
    )
  ).alias('preds')
).toPandas
```

I need to execute: `mypandasdf['preds'] = mypandasdf.preds.apply(eval)` to cast my string column to a list of dict.
I was wondering if there was any more efficient way to do it.
Any help? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you remove `to_json`?  `to_json` is to convert object into JSON string.

Comment: If I don't use `to_json`, the pandas column is just a list of: `[Row(score=0.08888888888888889, id='900048333'),...]`

Comment: Could you add a sample data?

Comment: There is no list of dict in this sample data.  If I execute your code minus the `to_json`, the `preds` column is an array of integer (`[50]` for 'Scott') and `toPandas()` will kept as the integer array.